# Why was East Pakistan never divided into multiple provinces?

Tags: political-history, population, pakistan, bangladesh

[East Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Pakistan) had a population much bigger than [West Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Pakistan). West Pakistan had multiple provinces, but the East had only one province.

This had been a recognized problem, and that was why [Mohammad Ali Bogra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Ali_Bogra) introduced the "[One Unit Sceme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Unit_Scheme)". I.e. he proposed that West Pakistan be ruled as a single unit.

As far as I know, this "One Unit Scheme" was annulled during [president Ayub Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayub_Khan_(general))'s rule.

During the rule of [Yahya Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahya_Khan), 162 seats of a total of 313 seats of the National Assembly were assigned to East Pakistan. EP had monolithic politics. As a result, [Mujib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheikh_Mujibur_Rahman)’s [Awami League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awami_League) was [in control of all of those seats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Pakistani_general_election). On the other hand, WP was fragmented into several provinces where Each province had different political dynamics.

When Mujib proposed [6-points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_point_movement), he was in an advantageous position from the perspective of secession. If there were multiple provinces in EP, Mujib couldn’t have been in control of the entire EP.

Why was not East Pakistan divided into multiple provinces during president Ayub Khan's rule?

Comment: Hi. You should link to some of the people and events in your question. Where you put "cessation", did you really mean "secession"?

Comment: [Why] questions are hard to answer; "why not" are harder.

Comment: Was there ever a proposal to do this?

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. Geographic (hard-to-travel geography can require devolution of power). Ethnic (Bangladesh is far more homogenous than (West) Pakistan). Cultural. Long term history. Recent history. Or based on the political continencies of that particular time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue for the "6-points" proposition you mention to become a reality is chronology: AYub Khan ended in 1969 its presidency, and only two years later the 1971 India-Pakistan war forced the secession of the 2 Pakistan into Pakistan and Bangladesh.

So basically the "natural" resistance of a political and social system in place to be changed delayed any division of East Pakistan, and any further attempts could not be made because of the outcome of 1971 war.

EDIT:

By "natural resistance" I speak about the fact that a political system is made of institutions and people in those institutions: to make those institutions change, one needs to convince people in these institutions. Time needed for that is "natural resistance"

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I am not talking about the implementation of *six-points*. You misread the question.

Comment: But I don't understand the exact question: you have the answer in your question with the "monolithic politics" of EP

Comment: Splitting EP into multiple provinces could have been a way to disrupt the monolithic politics of AL and Sheikh Mujibur Rahman. Hence, it could have been a way to stop the split of Pakistan.

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by explaining what is meant by "natural resistance".